# php include xhtml1-strict.dtd

Tags: php, authentication, xhtml

I have a simple index.php file which checks for user authentication, and if all is ok includes index.html file with user gallery:

```
<?php
if(!user_is_authenticated()) {
    header("location: http://someloginsite");
}
include("index.html");
?>
```

I have an issue with xhtml1-strict.dtd index.html declaration - if the html file included is declared as mentioned I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /var/www/.../index.html on line 1
```

With all other declarations it works fine... What am I missing?

Comment: What is this `if(!user_is_authenticated) {
` Should not there be a `$` or `()` if it is a function

Comment: Hi, sorry, ou course there is (), I retyped it incorrectly... The function itself works fine with all other declarations... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the xml declaration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
^^ <-- here
```

It looks like php. Either turn off short tags or echo the declaration

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
```